# Dot Net Nuke page is unable to be edited after changing permissions

Tags: dotnetnuke

This is my first time looking at Dot Net Nuke. I have a customer who set a page to only be visible to unregistered users. It will not show up when signed in as an administrator.

About Us showing up as a guest/unregistered user:

[image: Screenshot; About Us showing up as a guest/unregistered user]

About Us not showing up as a registered user/administrator:

[image: Screenshot; About Us not showing up as a registered user/administrator]

I am able to copy the page, but can't place it at the top since the original page already exists. I was trying to find a way to edit the database to undo the permissions changes but haven't been successful at that.

Answer (score 0):

If you login as a super user, you should be able to go to the Pages Persona Bar item, select the page in question, and edit its permissions.  You can edit any page from the Persona Bar's Pages item.

If you are using an earlier version of DNN, you can use the Admin, Page Management page to accomplish this.

Comment: Oh ... the correct name of the project is DNN.  The old name is DotNetNuke, one word.  <g>